# Unity desktop displays nothing in the workspace

Tags: 16.04, unity, display

From past 2-3 days, unity desktop doesn't display anything in the workspace other than launcher and menu bar.

[image: Please see the image]

I have tried reinstalling the unity desktop, booting in recovery mode and trying to repair it, but nothing seems to work. I had face something similar long time ago. I think I ended up reinstalling the OS last time.

Any clue to what is happening? Any suggestions appreciated.

**PS:** *Setup*: Ubuntu 16.04 on Parallels

Comment: Did you change the graphics driver, or the monitor resolution? It is hard to say what's happening without knowing what has happened before.

Comment: In Unity, the desktop is managed by nautilus (the default file manager). Have you tried resetting/reinstalling nautilus?

Comment: @user68186: Yeah I was trying to increase the default video memory allocated by parallels. But I never changed the graphics driver.

Comment: @danzel: Yep. I tried that.. It changed nothing.